# Why R survAUC::AUC functions require both training and test data?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, auc

I am familiar with binary classification models, where the AUC is the metric from the area under the specificity-sensitivity curve, it indicates the performance on a dataset.

Now, I'd like to assess the performance of Cox proportional hazard models. I thought about using an AUC-related metric. One approach is using package `survAUC`. The functions in R package `survAUC` require both the training and the test data to run, and there are differences in the results if you swap them around. For example:

```
library(survival)
library(survAUC)

TR <- ovarian[1:16,]
TE <- ovarian[17:26,]
train.fit  <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age,
                    x=TRUE, y=TRUE, method="breslow", data=TR)
Surv.rsp <- Surv(TR$futime, TR$fustat)
Surv.rsp.new <- Surv(TE$futime, TE$fustat)
times <- seq(10, 1000, 10)

# train/test - "right" setup
AUC.hc(Surv.rsp, Surv.rsp.new, predict(train.fit, newdata=TE), times)
# 0.9299145

#train/train
AUC.hc(Surv.rsp, Surv.rsp, predict(train.fit, newdata=TR), times)
# 0.9142284

#test/test
AUC.hc(Surv.rsp.new, Surv.rsp.new, predict(train.fit, newdata=TE), times)
# 0.8391204
```

Why are both datasets required? And why are the results differ if I have them differently? What is actually being measured?

Would it be a better option to use `survcomp::concordance.index` [instead](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/survcomp.html)? The package seems to be better maintained, and the options are clear for a single dataset.

Comment: In Scikit similar functions, the requirement for training data is to estimate the censoring distribution - https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/sksurv.metrics.concordance_index_ipcw.html

Comment: The AUC-like measures, including the concordance index, aren't very sensitive. See for example Frank Harrell's [post on 'Statistically Efficient Ways to Quantify Added Predictive Value of New Measurements'](https://www.fharrell.com/post/addvalue/). He developed the concordance index for survival models. His [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) provides ways to validate and evaluate calibration of many types of regression models, including Cox models.